# Does this NodeJS custom ORM approach support database connection pooling?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, connection-pooling

I have a file which creates the database connection pool called pool.js like this

```
import mysql from 'mysql2';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    connectionLimit: 5
}).promise();

export default pool;
```

A Base model class which handles query execution like this

```
import pool from './pool.js'

class BaseModel{
    async runSQL(sql){
        const [rows] = await pool.query(sql, this.params)
        return rows
    }
}
```

And a User model class which calls the base model database method like this

```
import BaseModel from "../helpers/BaseModel.js"

class User extends BaseModel{
    async create(props){
        const response = await this.runSQL(sql)
        return response
    }
}

export default new User
```

Does this implementation satisfy the database connection pooling usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are using connection pooling in the right way.

If you need more control on connection pool, you can play with a couple of more params like `maxIdle` or `idleTimeout`.

```
connectionLimit: 10,
maxIdle: 10, // max idle connections, the default value is the same as connectionLimit
idleTimeout: 60000, // idle connections timeout, in milliseconds, the default value 60000
```

You can find more infos [here](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2#using-connection-pools).

Just remember that (from the linked docs)

> The pool does not create all connections upfront but creates them on demand until the connection limit is reached.

Comment: Does it not create a new pool, everytime the User model is included and thus creating a new User object?

Comment: no, because modules are cached and initialized only the first time you import them. This is true with es modules and with commonjs modules as well (the modules you include by using "require"). You can verify it by checking this https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-evvvu7?file=index.js

Comment: now that I'm reading better at your code, you probably want to export not an istance class of user, but the class itself from user module. So you should export "User" and call "new User()" when you need. But beyond this, connection pooling specifically is ok.

Comment: The object is exported instead of the class so that I can call its methods directly after import. Does this break the connection pooling?

Comment: no, connection pooling is not affected

Comment: cool. Thanks alot. Is the exporting a new object not a good practice though? It helps to directly call the methods instead of creating an object after every import.

Comment: it really depends on what you are doing. A user istance should represent a specific user and there is no need to keep it in memory. You can instantiate a specific user istance when you need it. Imagine for example if you want to associate any static property to this istance, like an id property. You will have a single istance in the whole project with a setted id property. I would suggest to use an ORM like sequelize if you want to use models, or just to use a functional approach with functions that executes queries instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: yeah, true that. But the project requires no ORM to be used (Monkeys sitting on top). So, I have created my own and it functions just like sequelize.  Sequelize also does the same thing if I'm not mistaken. Since I copied it's entire functionality

Comment: Using an ORM it's just a choice, not necessarily the best choice. I've seen very stable and well coded projects built without any ORM, just with an SQL driver or a query builder like knex.js. There are articles that discuss about ORM pro and cons. Personally, for most project I don't like to use them and I try to follow a functional approach, while keeping the code clean. My personal suggestion is: if you can't use an ORM, don't try to create your own. Just go with a functional approach and define a methods that simply executes a queries. Your code will be also easier to unit-test with mocks

Comment: functional approach does not fit in my style of coding. But I get what you mean. Thanks for the help